# Block websites in an Android phone using JAVA

Tags: android

I want to block given URLs of an Android device using JAVA code. When user try to connect that URLs, it should be restrict. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You could write a proxy server, ask people to use the proxy server, and do your blocking in there.  But the user would have to opt into this, and removing your block would be a simple matter of removing the proxy server.